# Open App with Cortana UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, cortana

I have a command for Cortana who says a name, but this only works if the App is open. If I pronounce the commands with the closed app, the app opens but does not start the command. How can I actually open the app?

CortanaCommand.xml:

```
<CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="ExampleAppCommandSet_en-us">
<CommandPrefix> Open name </CommandPrefix>
<Example> Find a name </Example>
<Command Name="FindName">
  <Example> Find name  </Example>
  <ListenFor> Find name </ListenFor>
  <ListenFor> Find name </ListenFor>
  <Feedback> Find name </Feedback>
  <Navigate/>
</Command>
```

App.xaml.cs (public app):

```
public App()
    {
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
           Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata |
           Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }
```

App.xaml.cs (OnActivated):

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Was the app activated by a voice command?
        if (e.Kind != Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
        {
            return;
        }

        var commandArgs = e as Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs;

        var speechRecognitionResult = commandArgs.Result;
        string voiceCommandName = speechRecognitionResult.RulePath[0];
        string textSpoken = speechRecognitionResult.Text;

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        MainPage page = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
        if (page == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (voiceCommandName)
        {
            case "FindName":
                page.FindNameInList();
                break;

            default:
                // There is no match for the voice command name.
                break;
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var storageFile =
          await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
            new Uri("ms-appx:///CortanaCommand.xml"));
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinitionManager
            .InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(storageFile);
    }

    public async void FindNameInList()
    {
        MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();

        // The object for controlling the speech synthesis engine (voice).
        var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

        // Generate the audio stream from plain text.
        SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Your name, is, Jhon");

        // Send the stream to the media object.
        mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        mediaElement.Play();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So this is something that's not available in UWP. The closest you can come is that you open the cortana app and then say "FindName" and it'll work perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a background task to handle this case.

The official [Cortana voice command sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand) is for your reference.

You could check the [AdventureWorksVoiceCommandService.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand/cs/VoiceCommandService) to learn how to achieve it.